# drupal7 search form with 2 dropdown and submit button

Tags: drupal-modules

want to make a drupal module with 2 dropdown in which second drop down depend on first dropdown and a search button. After click on search button new page show with dropdown filter result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this module :

[hierarchical_select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

Comment: have taxonomy type data in first dropdown and content type data in second dropdown

Comment: in filter (first and second dropdown) you will have just a taxonomy vocabular, but in result (After click on search button) you will have the content list ==> exemple : http://wimleers.com/demo/hierarchical-select/taxonomy

Comment: thanks but i want to create module for search taxonomy and content when click on search then display the related result please sugest me a code example which work perfectly

Comment: i want to result on different page not on same page